# Really slow disc image creation (iso 9660) in C

Tags: c, iso9660

As a fun project I thought I'd write a program to make iso files. As far as I can tell it works, but it reads only 4KB every 30 seconds. I used eject -x 11 to slow my cdrom drive to a reasonable speed. Without it the drive runs at full speed and kills the process pretty quickly. Any suggestions to make this faster/better will be much appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define BUFFSIZE 4092

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("/dev/cdrom", "r");
    FILE *file = fopen(strcat(argv[1], ".iso"), "w");

    printf("Copying...\n");

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        char *line=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFSIZE);
        fgets(line, BUFFSIZE, fp);
        fprintf(file, "%s",line);

        free(line);
    }//end while

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(file);

    printf("Done!\n");

    return 0;
}//end main
```

Comment: You probably want to open files in binary mode; it's probably a bad idea to overwrite `argv[1]` like that; get rid of the cast

Comment: Bold use of string functions to read/write arbitrary binary data...

Answer (score 3):

`fgets()` handles text and is line oriented, and wastes time looking for newlines.  Furthermore, it and `fprintf()` don't handle `NUL` bytes, and can get very confused by them.  You want to use binary IO, i.e. `fread()` and `fwrite()`.  There is also no need to continually `free()` and reallocate your buffer.

If you want to use Unix IO primitives rather than the C wrappers, you could use `read()` and `write()` or `mmap()` instead.

Comment: that, and make the buffer (much) larger

Answer (score 1):

- Buffered IO is hardly appropriate in
  this scenario, neither is fgets which
  scans the input for a newline. Look
  into [mmap](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html).
- Continuous buffer
  de/re-allocation slows you down.
- Fprintf is not right for writing binary data. It's also slow.

Answer (score 0):

I am no C guru, but sounds like you need to implement some form of buffered readers and writers of data to see performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wouldn't go with formatted input (`fgets` & text mode), but with raw binary input (`fopen` with the `b` flag, `fread` and `fwrite` for writing). This way stdio doesn't need to perform the substitutions needed for the text mode (if needed on your platform), and you have a series of fixed-size reads that should perform better than `fgets`' waiting for the `\n`.

Then, I would get rid of that dynamic memory allocation; the continuous allocation/deallocation is probably killing the performance of your application. Just allocate once for all a static buffer on the stack (e.g. 8192 bytes) and use it all the time.

Answer (score -1):

Move the `malloc` and `free` outside the loop.